# mkdir call getting failed in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory using Perl. But this call fails.
However when I try to create the same directory structure in shell prompt, it works fine. 
Could someone please let me know why I am not able to create the directory in the directory structure?
Example:

```
$absolutepath = "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata";
print $absolutepath."\n";
mkdir "$absolutepath" or die $!;
```

In this example, `localdatafs1`, `Domino`, `mail\abhy.nsf`, and `Sent` are directories that already exist. I want to create a directory called `metadata` in the directory structure `/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata` using Perl. This mkdir call fails.

If I execute the command

```
mkdir /localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata
```

in shell prompt, the directory gets created successfully.

Why I am unable to create the directory in Perl using the above path?

Comment: Is your path supposed to contain the `\a` character?

Comment: What does the `die` message tell you?

Comment: It looks like you have a "\" instead of a "/" between "mail" and "abhy.nsf" Have you tried swapping the direction of your "\"?

Comment: @TimN: The path should contain the \a.

Comment: @BrianRoach: die message says 
No such file or directory at ./transfer.pl

Comment: @JohnMark: The directory that I need to create should be like mail\abhy.nsf. I need '\'.

Comment: The post has been edited to the point of removing the problem. The supposedly working `mkdir` cannot possibly work. Reverted those edits.

Comment: @ikegami - sorry, didn't notice the indenting changed the escaping, I hadn't actually changed his original text. He had used `\\` to make the backslash appear in the original post apparently.

Comment: @ikegami: I am confused. The path that i want to create is "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata". After mail, 2 back slashes are there in my code to escape a backslash. SO the path in the code is "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata". The directory named"mail\abhy.nsf" is already there in the system.

Comment: @BrianRoach Now if the try creating the folder using mkdir "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata" in the perl code, it fails. However the same command mkdir "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata" passes.

Comment: If you use `$absolutepath = "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata";` you shouldn't get `No such file or directory`.

Comment: What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($absolutepath));` IMPORTANT: Copy the entire response, and place it in backtickets (`\``).

Answer (score 4):

Your shell understands a different language than Perl. In your shell, the code

```
/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata
```

produces the string

```
/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata
```

In Perl, the code

```
"/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata"
```

produces the string

```
/localdatafs1/Domino/mail?bhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata
```

where the `?` represents a non-printable control character. The Perl code

```
"/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata"
```

produces the desired string. Note the escaped "`\`".

Answer (score 3):

```
$path = "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata"
                                  ^--- escape character, turning the path into

$path = "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail".chr(1)."bhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata"
```

Comment: Or you can use `mail\\abhy.nsf` if you actually want a backslash in the name, but that's generally not a good idea.

Comment: I have used the directory structure as "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata".
mkdir "/localdatafs1/Domino/mail\\abhy.nsf/Sent/Metadata" is getting failed.

Comment: @Rajath: yes, becaues `\\` is not a directory separator on Unix/Linux systems. You can't mix / and \ for paths in Unix, they have to be /